# How to get recently viewed images in Android

Tags: android, gallery, recent-file-list, android-recents

Im a beginner in android..I would like to know how to retrieve the recently viewed images/svideos in the gallery programmatically..Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stock gallery app does not have any API's to let you do this. Even if it did, manufacturers provide their own gallery apps with custom android skins like Samsung Touchwiz, HTC Sense etc and they usually aren't the same as the stock gallery app.